# phpMyAdmin isn't working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php-ini, php

When I run phpmyadmin it shows me this message:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
```

I have modified my php.ini to have the correct address to the php_mysqli.dll, uncommented it.
I have even copied and renamed it into mysqli.dll. 
Then restarted the pc, and nothing works. Here I paste the phpinfo();

```
Build Date  May 15 2012 00:57:24
Compiler    MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x64
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--without-dblib" "--without-pdo-dblib" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_10_2\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x64\deps\instantclient_11_2\sdk,shared" "--disable-debug-pack" "--disable-static-analyze"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API 20100412
PHP Extension   20100525
Zend Extension  220100525
Zend Extension Build    API220100525,TS,VC9
PHP Extension Build API20100525,TS,VC9
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  disabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

PHP Credits

Configuration

apache2handler

Apache Version  Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
Apache API Version  20120211
Server Administrator    admin@localhost
Hostname:Port   localhost:80
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  No
Server Root C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2
Loaded Modules  core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_setenvif mod_php5

Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  1   1
last_modified   0   0
xbithack    0   0

Apache Environment

Variable    Value
HTTP_HOST   localhost
HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  max-age=0
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip,deflate,sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
PATH    C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;
SystemRoot  C:\windows
COMSPEC C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
PATHEXT .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
WINDIR  C:\windows
SERVER_SIGNATURE    no value
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
SERVER_NAME localhost
SERVER_ADDR 127.0.0.1
SERVER_PORT 80
REMOTE_ADDR 127.0.0.1
DOCUMENT_ROOT   C:/wamp/www/
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
CONTEXT_PREFIX  no value
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   C:/wamp/www/
SERVER_ADMIN    admin@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME C:/wamp/www/pruebaSQL.php
REMOTE_PORT 50605
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI /pruebaSQL.php
SCRIPT_NAME /pruebaSQL.php

HTTP Headers Information

HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /pruebaSQL.php HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost
Connection  keep-alive
Cache-Control   max-age=0
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
HTTP Response Headers
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.3

bcmath

BCMath support  enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0

calendar

Calendar support    enabled

com_dotnet

COM support enabled
DCOM support    disabled
.Net support    enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
com.allow_dcom  0   0
com.autoregister_casesensitive  1   1
com.autoregister_typelib    0   0
com.autoregister_verbose    0   0
com.code_page   no value    no value
com.typelib_file    no value    no value

Core

PHP Version 5.4.3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   On  On
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting no value    no value
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   C:\php  C:\php
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .;C:\php\pear   .;C:\php\pear
log_errors  Off Off
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  -1  -1
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    0   0
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  On  On
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   no value    no value
serialize_precision 17  17
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order EGPCS   EGPCS
windows.show_crt_warning    Off Off
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.detect_unicode On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value

ctype

ctype functions enabled

date


date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2012.2
Timezone Database   internal
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in C:\wamp\www\pruebaSQL.php on line 2
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0008  239088  {main}( )   ..\pruebaSQL.php:0
2   0.0008  239696  phpinfo ( ) ..\pruebaSQL.php:2
Default timezone UTC 
Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value

dom

DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.7.8
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled

ereg

Regex Library   Bundled library enabled

filter

Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Id: e523cdc8829892d1b4f9cb7c3c57b2ba1c36b9ea $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp

FTP support enabled

hash

hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv

iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    "libiconv"
iconv library version   1.11

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

json

json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1

libxml

libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version 2.7.8
libXML Loaded Version   20708
libXML streams  enabled

mcrypt

mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version 2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes arcfour
Supported modes cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

mhash

MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support

mysqlnd

mysqlnd enabled
Version mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: b0b3b15c693b7f6aeb3aa66b646fee339f175e39 $
Compression supported
SSL supported
Command buffer size 4096
Read buffer size    32768
Read timeout    31536000
Collecting statistics   Yes
Collecting memory statistics    No
Tracing n/a
Loaded plugins  mysqlnd,example,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
API Extensions  no value

mysqlnd statistics  
bytes_sent  0
bytes_received  0
packets_sent    0
packets_received    0
protocol_overhead_in    0
protocol_overhead_out   0
bytes_received_ok_packet    0
bytes_received_eof_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_header_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_row_packet  0
bytes_received_prepare_response_packet  0
bytes_received_change_user_packet   0
packets_sent_command    0
packets_received_ok 0
packets_received_eof    0
packets_received_rset_header    0
packets_received_rset_field_meta    0
packets_received_rset_row   0
packets_received_prepare_response   0
packets_received_change_user    0
result_set_queries  0
non_result_set_queries  0
no_index_used   0
bad_index_used  0
slow_queries    0
buffered_sets   0
unbuffered_sets 0
ps_buffered_sets    0
ps_unbuffered_sets  0
flushed_normal_sets 0
flushed_ps_sets 0
ps_prepared_never_executed  0
ps_prepared_once_executed   0
rows_fetched_from_server_normal 0
rows_fetched_from_server_ps 0
rows_buffered_from_client_normal    0
rows_buffered_from_client_ps    0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered    0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered  0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered    0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered  0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor  0
rows_affected_normal    0
rows_affected_ps    0
rows_skipped_normal 0
rows_skipped_ps 0
copy_on_write_saved 0
copy_on_write_performed 0
command_buffer_too_small    0
connect_success 0
connect_failure 0
connection_reused   0
reconnect   0
pconnect_success    0
active_connections  0
active_persistent_connections   0
explicit_close  0
implicit_close  0
disconnect_close    0
in_middle_of_command_close  0
explicit_free_result    0
implicit_free_result    0
explicit_stmt_close 0
implicit_stmt_close 0
mem_emalloc_count   0
mem_emalloc_amount  0
mem_ecalloc_count   0
mem_ecalloc_amount  0
mem_erealloc_count  0
mem_erealloc_amount 0
mem_efree_count 0
mem_efree_amount    0
mem_malloc_count    0
mem_malloc_amount   0
mem_calloc_count    0
mem_calloc_amount   0
mem_realloc_count   0
mem_realloc_amount  0
mem_free_count  0
mem_free_amount 0
mem_estrndup_count  0
mem_strndup_count   0
mem_estndup_count   0
mem_strdup_count    0
proto_text_fetched_null 0
proto_text_fetched_bit  0
proto_text_fetched_tinyint  0
proto_text_fetched_short    0
proto_text_fetched_int24    0
proto_text_fetched_int  0
proto_text_fetched_bigint   0
proto_text_fetched_decimal  0
proto_text_fetched_float    0
proto_text_fetched_double   0
proto_text_fetched_date 0
proto_text_fetched_year 0
proto_text_fetched_time 0
proto_text_fetched_datetime 0
proto_text_fetched_timestamp    0
proto_text_fetched_string   0
proto_text_fetched_blob 0
proto_text_fetched_enum 0
proto_text_fetched_set  0
proto_text_fetched_geometry 0
proto_text_fetched_other    0
proto_binary_fetched_null   0
proto_binary_fetched_bit    0
proto_binary_fetched_tinyint    0
proto_binary_fetched_short  0
proto_binary_fetched_int24  0
proto_binary_fetched_int    0
proto_binary_fetched_bigint 0
proto_binary_fetched_decimal    0
proto_binary_fetched_float  0
proto_binary_fetched_double 0
proto_binary_fetched_date   0
proto_binary_fetched_year   0
proto_binary_fetched_time   0
proto_binary_fetched_datetime   0
proto_binary_fetched_timestamp  0
proto_binary_fetched_string 0
proto_binary_fetched_blob   0
proto_binary_fetched_enum   0
proto_binary_fetched_set    0
proto_binary_fetched_geometry   0
proto_binary_fetched_other  0
init_command_executed_count 0
init_command_failed_count   0
com_quit    0
com_init_db 0
com_query   0
com_field_list  0
com_create_db   0
com_drop_db 0
com_refresh 0
com_shutdown    0
com_statistics  0
com_process_info    0
com_connect 0
com_process_kill    0
com_debug   0
com_ping    0
com_time    0
com_delayed_insert  0
com_change_user 0
com_binlog_dump 0
com_table_dump  0
com_connect_out 0
com_register_slave  0
com_stmt_prepare    0
com_stmt_execute    0
com_stmt_send_long_data 0
com_stmt_close  0
com_stmt_reset  0
com_stmt_set_option 0
com_stmt_fetch  0
com_deamon  0
bytes_received_real_data_normal 0
bytes_received_real_data_ps 0

example statistics  
stat1   0
stat2   0

odbc

ODBC Support    enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
ODBC library    Win32

Directive   Local Value Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent   On  On
odbc.check_persistent   On  On
odbc.default_cursortype Static cursor   Static cursor
odbc.default_db no value    no value
odbc.default_pw no value    no value
odbc.default_user   no value    no value
odbc.defaultbinmode return as is    return as is
odbc.defaultlrl return up to 4096 bytes return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.12 2011-01-15

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers no value

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.1
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: 2a47d3d0354109d8077e34d59f1228ccfd021d59 $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives enabled
ZIP-based phar archives enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   disabled (install pecl/bz2)
Native OpenSSL support  enabled

Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On

Reflection

Reflection  enabled
Version $Id: 1cf65cee164ed57874ce2d29e5c46b82f6139524 $

session

Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

SimpleXML

Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: 455280fc74f9f002b7314def7a456f6c3080eb92 $
Schema support  enabled

SPL

SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard

Dynamic Library Support enabled
Internal Sendmail Support for Windows   enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset=  a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset=
user_agent  no value    no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support   enabled

wddx

WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer enabled

xdebug

xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.0
IDE Key 

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.manual_url   http://www.php.net  http://www.php.net
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  \   \
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir \   \
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3

xml

XML Support active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version 2.7.8

xmlreader

XMLReader   enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter   enabled

zip

Zip enabled
Extension Version   $Id$
Zip version 1.9.1
Libzip version  0.9.0

zlib

ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.7
Linked Version  1.2.7

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value





**PHP Variables**

Variable    Value
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    localhost
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]   max-age=0
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip,deflate,sdch
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"]  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
_SERVER["PATH"] C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;
_SERVER["SystemRoot"]   C:\windows
_SERVER["COMSPEC"]  C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
_SERVER["PATHEXT"]  .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
_SERVER["WINDIR"]   C:\windows
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] no value
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  localhost
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    C:/wamp/www/
_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]   http
_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]   no value
_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    C:/wamp/www/
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] admin@localhost
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  C:/wamp/www/pruebaSQL.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  50605
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /pruebaSQL.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /pruebaSQL.php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /pruebaSQL.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]   1343063976.618
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1343063976
_SERVER["argv"] 
Array
(
)
_SERVER["argc"] 0
```

There in pjpinfo() shows me a warning but I couldnt figure out why, it is something from date(), even when I am not using it. but I dont believe that is the problem.

I installed WAMP(latest version) on a windows7 x64 machine.

Please help, I have been stuck in there for over a week

Answer (score 0):

wamp have two php.ini files. one is in PHP folder and another one in apache\bin folder. you have to modify the apache folder php.ini file.

Otherwise through system tray wamp icon also you can open the ini file. conform that whether you have modified the correct file. and check the phpinfo whether MYSQLI is enabled